# Problem with derivation of Dirac equation

Tags: field-theory, conventions, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

In my book on QFT (Lancaster & Blundell) while deriving the Dirac equation, they arrive at the following result:
$$(\partial ^2 +m^{2})=(\not\!\partial -im)(\not\!\partial+im)$$
They then state:
"......take the plus-sign bracket and treat it as an operator acting on the wave function $\psi(x)$,
$$(\not\!\partial +im)\psi(x)=0"$$
which I assume follows from the Klein-Gordon equation $$(\partial^{2}+m^{2})\psi(x)=0$$ (in natural units)
However, my question is that if that is the case, shouldn't it be equally likely that $$(\not\!\partial -im)\psi(x)=0$$ which would lead to a change of sign in the Dirac equation?

Comment: It makes no difference. Just conjugate by $\gamma^5$ and the sign of the mass changes.

Comment: Their logic doesn’t really make any sense... it’s not a “derivation” at all. When you read these “intuitive” QFT books, you should think of the presentation as a set of evocative sketches which bear some slight visual resemblance to how an actual derivation would be carried out. If you try to make their logic precise you’ll just get confused...